# Ĉu ekzistas feminisma movado en Esperantujo?

Tags: culture, movado

Mi iam ricevis invitadon al kelkaj interesaj grupoj fejsbuke, kiuj estas Esperantistaj grupoj, sed mi ankoraŭ ne trovis iun aktivan feminisman grupon. Ĉu ekzistas?

Answer (score 9):

Ekzistas grupo kiu nomiĝas [Egalecen](https://egalecen.org/pri-ni/) kaj ili multe aktivas pri feminismaj temoj. De ilia retpaĝo:

> Ni estas kolektaĵo de Esperantistoj, kiuj celas blogi pri [pluraneca](https://egalecen.org/2014/08/04/pluraneco/) feminismo en Esperanto. Ni esperas, ke per nia blogo ni povas antaŭenpuŝi Esperantujon al la nivelo de socijusteca komunikado kaj interkompreno de aliaj neesperantaj feminismaj rondoj.

Answer (score 4):

Ekzistas esperant-lingva grupo ["Feminismo kaj egaleco"](https://feminismo.telegramo.org/) kun 114 membroj je la tujmesaĝilo Telegram.

Comment: Mi kreis ĝin! :-D Dankon pro la respondo.

Answer (score 0):

Ekde kiam mi starigis la demandon mi multe parolis kun esperantistoj pri la temo kaj trovis la sekvajn revuojn:

Sekso kaj egaleco (eldonita en la 70aj kaj 80aj jaroj)

http://www.gazetoteko.com/ske/

kaj

Femina, revuo fondita de la Feminisma Esperanta Movado (FEM).
https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femina

Aldone estas grupo en Facebook nomata Seksa egaleco en Esperanto:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/1994187464155216/?ref=br_rs

TEJO en 2017-2019 faris egalecan projekton, vidu la video pri la projekto [Florigu Egalecon inter Junuloj ĉe Jutubo](https://youtu.be/wZLB0SyX1mU) kaj legu [pri la projekto en la retpaĝo.](https://genraegaleco.tejo.org/agado/)